# Changing BizTalk 2020 Deployment Project name stops DevOps deploying the application correctly

Tags: deployment, azure-pipelines, devops, release, biztalk-2020

BizTalk 2020 - We changed the BizTalk Server Application deployment project name, which was the same name as the solution name which also matched the BizTalk application name, to something different. Rebuilt solution and synchronise with DevOps, re-deploy the BizTalk application via the DevOps Release pipeline. No errors reported but when we look at the deployed application on the BizTalk 2020 server, it's not got the latest changes we made after changing the deployment project name. (Again no errors reported in the application log either) It looks like changing the name has somehow stopped the release pipeline seeing the latest solution .zip file. Changing the project name back again fixes the issue but what if we want to change the name? Are there some rules on what project name we use here? I.e. Should the project name be the same as the BizTalk application name? Is there something we've missing somewhere in how we changed the project name?

We're running on Windows Server 2016, Visual Studio 2019, BizTalk 2020 Developer edition with CU1.

Appreciate hearing from anyone who has seen this behaviour and might suggest a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following items:

1. Check how you rename the application name. Right-click your newly-added application project, and select **Properties**. Customize the **Application Name** you want displayed in BizTalk Administration:

[image]

2. Try to remove and re-configure an agent:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#replace-an-agent

3. Check your **Publish Artifact** task in **Build** Pipeline, in `Path to publish`, to see if you select the correct application project folder.

More details of deployment with DevOps in BizTalk Server, you may refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configure-automatic-deployment-with-visual-studio-team-services-in-biztalk?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: It was option 3 - Publish Artifact task in the Build pipeline, which was still pointing to the old project name. Updated this and hey presto - it's working!! Many thanks for you help with this.